# How to sign Amazon Simple Pay button in node.js / Javascript

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-pay

I've spent the past 6 hours trying to follow Amazon's instructions for signing a Simple Pay button form in node.js. I can't get it to the accept the sig and I've tried every permutation of the confusing instructions. Can anyone help me out of my misery?

The error I get is

> Input parameter signature is invalid

Here is my procedure

```
var params={
    "returnUrl": "[confidential]",
    "ipnUrl": "[confidential]",
    "processImmediate": "1",
    "accessKey" :"[AWS key]",
    "collectShippingAddress" :"0",
    "isDonationWidget" :"0",
    "amazonPaymentsAccountId" :"[the button generator creates this but there is no mention in the docs]",
    "referenceId" :ref,
    "cobrandingStyle" :"logo",
    "immediateReturn" :"1",
    "amount" :"USD "+amount,
    "description" : desc,
    "abandonUrl" :"[confidential]",
    "signatureMethod": "HmacSHA256", //docs not clear if signatureMethod and signatureVersion should be included, but I've tried all permutations and can't get it to work
    "signatureVersion" :"2"
    }
        //Docs say it should confirm to     
    /*
    StringToSign = HTTPVerb + "\n" +
    ValueOfHostHeaderInLowercase + "\n" +
    HTTPRequestURI + "\n" +         
    CanonicalizedQueryString <from the preceding step>
   */
    //sort parameters (natural byte order)
    var p=_.pairs(params);
    var psorted=_.sortBy(p, function(p) { return p[0];});
    //start to construct the form
    var input='';
    for(var i=0; i<psorted.length;i++) {
        input+="<input type='hidden' name='"+psorted[i][0]+"' value='"+psorted[i][1]+"'>";
    }
    //prepare the string to be signed
    var qstring='POST'+'\n';
    qstring+='https://authorize.payments.amazon.com'+'\n';
    qstring+='/pba/paypipeline'+'\n';
    for(var i=0; i<psorted.length;i++) {
        psorted[i][0]=encodeURI(psorted[i][0]);
        psorted[i][1]=encodeURI(psorted[i][1]);
        qstring+=psorted[i][0]+'='+psorted[i][1];
        if (i<psorted.length-1) {qstring+='&';} 
    };

    console.log(qstring+'\n\n');
    var sig=crypto.createHmac("SHA256", "[AWS Secret Key") 6
        .update(qstring)
        .digest('base64');
    input+="<input type='hidden' name='signature' value='"+sig+"'>"; //doesn't matter whether or not i url encode this
    console.log(input);
```

That converts the parameters into

```
POST
authorize.payments.amazon.com
/pba/paypipeline
abandonUrl=XXXX&accessKey=XXXXX&amazonPaymentsAccountId=XXXXXX&amount=USD%203&cobrandingStyle=logo&collectShippingAddress=0&description=sadasdd&immediateReturn=1&ipnUrl=XXXXXx&isDonationWidget=0&processImmediate=1&referenceId=324324&returnUrl=XXXXXXXX&signatureMethod=HmacSHA256&signatureVersion=2
```

I concatenate and paste the the output to this form for testing

```
<form action="https://authorize.payments.amazon.com/pba/paypipeline" method="POST">
  <input type='hidden' name='abandonUrl' value='[confidential]'>
  <input type='hidden' name='accessKey' value='[confidential]'>
  <input type='hidden' name='amazonPaymentsAccountId' value='[confidential]'>
  <input type='hidden' name='amount' value='USD 3'>
  <input type='hidden' name='cobrandingStyle' value='logo'>
  <input type='hidden' name='collectShippingAddress' value='0'>
  <input type='hidden' name='description' value='sadasdd'>
  <input type='hidden' name='immediateReturn' value='1'>
  <input type='hidden' name='ipnUrl' value='[confidential]'>
  <input type='hidden' name='isDonationWidget' value='0'>
  <input type='hidden' name='processImmediate' value='1'>
  <input type='hidden' name='referenceId' value='324324'>
  <input type='hidden' name='returnUrl' value='[confidential]'>
  <input type='hidden' name='signatureMethod' value='HmacSHA256'>
  <input type='hidden' name='signatureVersion' value='2'>
  <input type='hidden' name='signature' value='fHSA+p37r5ooOJOUnjYBdhNFe/pAEg/KunAEOudUvGs='>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Here are the Amazon docs

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonSimplePay/latest/ASPAdvancedUserGuide/Sig2CreateSignature.html

> How to Generate a Signature
>
> To create the signature
>
> Create the canonicalized query string that you need later in this
>   procedure:
>
> Sort the UTF-8 query string components by parameter name with natural
>   byte ordering.
>
> The parameters can come from the GET URI or from the POST body (when
>   Content-Type is application/x-www-form-urlencoded).
>
> URL encode the parameter name and values according to the following
>   rules:
>
> Do not URL encode any of the unreserved characters that RFC 3986
>   defines.
>
> These unreserved characters are A-Z, a-z, 0-9, hyphen ( - ),
>   underscore ( _ ), period ( . ), and tilde ( ~ ).
>
> Percent encode all other characters with %XY, where X and Y are hex
>   characters 0-9 and uppercase A-F.
>
> Percent encode extended UTF-8 characters in the form %XY%ZA....
>
> Percent encode the space character as %20 (and not +, as common
>   encoding schemes do).
>
> Note Currently all AWS service parameter names use unreserved
>   characters, so you don't need to encode them. However, you might want
>   to include code to handle parameter names that use reserved
>   characters, for possible future use. Separate the encoded parameter
>   names from their encoded values with the equals sign ( = ) (ASCII
>   character 61), even if the parameter value is empty.
>
> Separate the name-value pairs with an ampersand ( & ) (ASCII code 38).
>
> Create the string to sign according to the following pseudo-grammar
>   (the "\n" represents an ASCII newline).
>
> StringToSign = HTTPVerb + "\n" + ValueOfHostHeaderInLowercase + "\n" +
>   HTTPRequestURI + "\n" +          CanonicalizedQueryString  The HTTPRequestURI component is the HTTP absolute path
>   component of the URI up to, but not including, the query string. If
>   the HTTPRequestURI is empty, use a forward slash ( / ).
>
> Calculate an RFC 2104-compliant HMAC with the string you just created,
>   your Secret Access Key as the key, and SHA256 or SHA1 as the hash
>   algorithm.
>
> For more information, go to http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2104.txt.
>
> Convert the resulting value to base64.
>
> Use the resulting value as the value of the Signature request
>   parameter.
>
> Important The final signature you send in the request must be URL
>   encoded as specified in RFC 3986 (for more information, go to
>   http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3986.txt). If your toolkit URL encodes your
>   final request, then it handles the required URL encoding of the
>   signature. If your toolkit doesn't URL encode the final request, then
>   make sure to URL encode the signature before you include it in the
>   request. Most importantly, make sure the signature is URL encoded only
>   once. A common mistake is to URL encode it manually during signature
>   formation, and then again when the toolkit URL encodes the entire
>   request. For information on the high-level process for creating a
>   button, see Creating Button Forms Dynamically .
>
> In the following examples, new lines have been inserted to make the
>   examples easier to read. Explicit '\n' is used wherever new line is
>   required.
>
> The following is an example Amazon Simple Pay request using POST.
>
> The following is an example of a string to use for
>   StringToSign in the preceding example.
>
> POST\n authorize.payments-sandbox.amazon.com\n /pba/paypipeline\n
>   SignatureMethod=HmacSHA256 &SignatureVersion=2
>   &accessKey=YourCallerKey &amount=USD%201.1 &cobrandingStyle=logo
>   &description=Test%20Widget &immediateReturn=0
>   &ipnUrl=http%3A%2F%2Fyourwebsite.com%2Fipn &processImmediate=1
>   &referenceId=YourReferenceId
>   &returnUrl=http%3A%2F%2Fyourwebsite.com%2Freturn.html For more
>   examples of generating a signature, see Appendix: Sample Code.
>
> For information on signing your button form correctly, see How to Sign
>   your Button Form Correctly.

Comment: Edited question - first off, button type=image was sending x and y coordinates as part of the POST. JFC! But regrettably that did not fix anything.

Comment: I had http:// domain.com instead of domain.com - but still generates error. Curses!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For posterity, here is the solution:

1) Don't mess with Simple Pay Buttons - use FPS instead

2) Of the myriad overlapping documents, I found this to be the simplest and clearest: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonFPS/latest/FPSBasicGuide/SendingaCBUIRequest.html

3) Use encodeURIComponent not encodeURI - this was my biggest most frustrating mistake

This code will correctly sign an Amazon FPS request (assumes crypto for hmac and nconf for configuration)

```
var crypto = require('crypto');
var _ = require('underscore');
var nconf = require('nconf').argv().env().file({
    file: "./config.json"
});
exports.azPayRequest=function (amount, desc,ref) {
  var params={
    "returnUrl": nconf.get("awsPayments:returnURL"), //callback
    "callerKey" : nconf.get("awsPayments:callerKey"), //aws id
    "callerReference": ref,
    "pipelineName":"SingleUse",
    "cobrandingStyle" :"logo",
    "currencyCode" :"USD",
    "transactionAmount" : amount,
    "paymentReason" : desc,
    "signatureMethod": "HmacSHA256",
    "signatureVersion" :"2"
    }

    /*
    StringToSign = HTTPVerb + "\n" +
    ValueOfHostHeaderInLowercase + "\n" +
    HTTPRequestURI + "\n" +         
    CanonicalizedQueryString <from the preceding step>
    */

    //sort parameters
    var p=_.pairs(params);
    var psorted=_.sortBy(p, function(p) { return p[0];});

    //method, host, path
    var method='GET';
    var host=nconf.get('awsPayments:host'); // e.g., authorize.payments.amazon.com;
    var path=nconf.get('awsPayments:path'); //e.g. /cobranded-ui/actions/start;

    //url encode parameters
    var qstring='';
    for(var i=0; i<psorted.length;i++) {
        psorted[i][0]=encodeURIComponent(psorted[i][0]);
        psorted[i][1]=encodeURIComponent(psorted[i][1]);
        qstring+=psorted[i][0]+'='+psorted[i][1];
        if (i<psorted.length-1) {qstring+='&';} 
    };

    //calculate hmac
    var nl=String.fromCharCode(10);
    var encode_request=method+nl+host+nl+path+nl+qstring;
    console.log("STRING TO ENCODE\n"+encode_request+'\n\n');
    var sig=crypto.createHmac("SHA256", nconf.get("awsPayments:awsSecretAccessKey"))
        .update(encode_request)
        .digest('base64');

    var url="https://"+host+path+"?"+qstring+'&signature='+encodeURIComponent(sig);

    return url;
}
```

Comment: Of the myriad overlapping documents, I found http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/rest-signature.html most helpful in testing and tweaking the signature generation code. It's for a different Amazon API, but looks like the same process.